# Calculate screen coordinates for remote desktop application

Tags: java, screen, rdp

I am currently developing a remote desktop application in Java, but i am stuck on calculating the screen coordinates for remote mouse clicking.

For example, the remote computer has a resolution of `1024x768`, but the panel that renders the image and handles the clicks is only `800x600`.How can I calculate the coordinates, so when I press my panel in the upper right corner, it also clicks on the remote computer there?

I tried

```
x = clickedX / (remoteX/clickedX)
```

and

```
x = clickedX * (remoteX/clickedX)
```

but it never seemed to work.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You would need to add additional information, what are remoteX and clickedX, how do you get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I properly understand what you want to do, you are scaling your targets resolution up/down displaying a smaller/bigger image of the remote desktop.
So you need to calculate the transformation with the scale factor you use.

```
int targetWidth = 1024;
int targetHeight = 768;
int myWidth = 800;
int myHeight = 600;

double scaleX = targetWidth/myWidth;
double scaleY = targetHeight/myHeight;

double targetMouseX = myMouseX * scaleX; // 
double targetMouseY = myMouseY * scaleY; //
```

with targetMouseX & Y as your "output" and myMouseX&Y as your inputs, e.g. your mouse event.